# install gcc6 in archlinux

Tags: tensorflow, gcc, archlinux

The gcc version in my machine is 8.3. However, I need to use gcc6. I git cloned the source from AUR, and I run:

```
makepkg -si
```

It fails. It jumped into a look, checking everything again and again. The screen flashed so fast and I couldn't have a screenshot.
I tried to use yay to install gcc6 from AUR, it is the same problem.

Comment: There's no reason you need to take a screenshot, and screenshots are in fact the least recommended way of not giving useful information. Instead, link a pastebin with the textual output of the makepkg command, while providing the last few lines containing the error message, in your question.

Answer (score -1):

problem resolved.
I just download the package from the archive in archlinux AUR. and pacman.
I am not sure why I cannot use yay or makepkg -si to install it.
Totally no idea about it.

Comment: It's unclear how this is supposed to help, since the AUR archives only provide snapshot tarballs containing the source PKGBUILD, which pacman cannot install and which you must run makepkg in order to build before installing.

Comment: I just download the *.tar.xz file from AUR archive, and I use "sudo pacman -U *.tar.xz* to upgrade this package.